# How do I get a Phaser game onto the iOS App Store?

Tags: javascript, ios, phonegap, phaser-framework, cocoonjs

On my pc, I made a game with html, css, javascript, and phaser for the framework. I'd like to get this game on the iOS App Store. I have access to a mac so I could transfer my project onto it if I can't do everything on my pc.
What are my options for doing this? Or what would you recommend?

Comment: This is not a coding question.

Answer (score 1):

Releasing to the Apple App Store is a very stringent process, and there's really no room whatsoever for deviation from the intended process. You will outright **need** to transfer your project onto your Mac; iOS apps **cannot** be published without a Mac, as they require XCode to sign them.

Once you have your program on your Mac, you'll need to **[purchase a Developer Licence](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)** from Apple, making sure that you go for either `Individual` or `Organisation` (as those are the only licences that can publish to the Apple App Store). Note that not only do you need to join Apple's Developer Program, but **also** **[iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)** (though this is free)!

After obtaining your licence, and setting up both accounts, you'll need to create **[a Provisioning Profile certificate](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/)** for your developer(s) that you sign your app with through XCode, and create a **[unique identifier](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle)** for your application.

From there it's just a matter of publishing it to the **[Apple Developer Program.](http://developer.apple.com)**

Once you upload, it will be placed into a Beta Review by Apple's testing team. Assuming it passes, you can add in all of the relevant store data and submit it to the store itself. This process usually takes a few days.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! And will I need to somehow convert my project to an XCode project? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Assuming you are just dealing with HTML / CSS / JS, you simply create a new XCode project and copy over the files from `assets/www` to `www` in the XCode project folder, and then compile it. If you're doing anything in Java (or similar), you'll have to re-write all of that functionality in Objective C.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! How do I find the www in the Xcode project folder? Sorry I'm quite new to this... and I don't have a assets/www for my app, thank you!